# How can I run Spotify on a Raspberry Pi with the official Spotify interface?

Tags: touchscreen, windows, chromium

I want a version that has the official Spotify user interface, either the web player interface, or the standard program interface.

I don't like the interface of the XBMC (Kodi) Spotify add-ons, or the interface of Despotify, as they are very text based and involve using the back/forward buttons a lot, and hence don't work very well with small touch screens. However, if you look at the [web player interface](https://player.spotify.com/browse/genres), you can see this will work really well with a small Touch screen.

I essentially want to create a system that works very much like the android app for Spotify, but if I manage to get the web player or normal program working on the Raspbery Pi then I will not have the restrictions that are on the android app. I do not have Spotify premium. Is there a way I can achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use it on full screen chromium kiosk mode. As far as restriction of free account goes, buy premium.

Comment: @dastaan, I thought it didn't work with chromium because you cannot get flash on Linux? Also what restrictions will there be? I cannot afford premium at the moment, but I do not mind adverts. The only restrictions I want to avoid are the mobile app ones  (can only skip 5 times a day, and can only play songs in shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome with kiosk mode, or any other browser that supports that.
The browser version of Spotify works quite well.

Also, if you want to get rid of the ads, use an adblocker, but premium isn't that much.